# Populating a TableView with a HashMap that will update when HashMap changes

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tableview, observablelist

I have followed this post

[Binding hashmap with tableview (JavaFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618653/binding-hashmap-with-tableview-javafx)

and created a TableView that is populated by data from a HashMap.

The `TableView` receives its data from a `HashMap` called `map` by creating an `ObservableList` from `map.entrySet()` and handing that `ObservableList` off to the `TableView`'s constructor.  (Code is below)

However, although it's an `ObservableList` with `SimpleStringProperty`s, the TableView does not update when changes are made to the underlying HashMap.

Here is my code:

```
public class MapTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            // sample data
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("one", "One");
            map.put("two", "Two");
            map.put("three", "Three");


            // use fully detailed type for Map.Entry<String, String> 
            TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Key");
            column1.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p) {
                    // this callback returns property for just one cell, you can't use a loop here
                    // for first column we use key
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey());
                }
            });

            TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Value");
            column2.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p) {
                    // for second column we use value
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getValue());
                }
            });

            ObservableList<Map.Entry<String, String>> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet());
            final TableView<Map.Entry<String,String>> table = new TableView<>(items);

            table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);

            Button changeButton = new Button("Change");
            changeButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                map.put("two", "2");
                System.out.println(map);
            });
            VBox vBox = new VBox(8);
            vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, changeButton);

            Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }  catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

This is exactly the code from [Binding hashmap with tableview (JavaFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618653/binding-hashmap-with-tableview-javafx) except I have added the following button:

```
        Button changeButton = new Button("Change");
        changeButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            map.put("two", "2");
            System.out.println(map);
        });
```

which I then add to a VBox with the TableView.

When I click the button, the `TableView` is not updated.  However, I can verify that the underlying `HashMap` has indeed changed because of the `System.out.println(map)` output.  Also when I click on a column header in the `TableView` to sort the data by one column, the new updated value appears after the table data is re-sorted.

How can I make the table update automatically when the underlying map is changed?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: I didn't look into this in detail, but perhaps you want to use an [ObservableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableMap-java.util.Map-).

Comment: Maybe this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21339428/2855515

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `ObservableMap` with a listener that keeps the `TableView` items and the keys of the map the same and use the `cellValueFactory` with [`Bindings.valueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#valueAt-javafx.collections.ObservableMap-K-), e.g.:

```
ObservableMap<String, String> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

ObservableList<String> keys = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends String> change) -> {
    boolean removed = change.wasRemoved();
    if (removed != change.wasAdded()) {
        // no put for existing key
        if (removed) {
            keys.remove(change.getKey());
        } else {
            keys.add(change.getKey());
        }
    }
});

map.put("one", "One");
map.put("two", "Two");
map.put("three", "Three");

final TableView<String> table = new TableView<>(keys);

TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Key");
// display item value (= constant)
column1.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> cd.getValue()));

TableColumn<String, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Value");
column2.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.valueAt(map, cd.getValue()));

table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works beautifully!  Interesting approach, making it a table of Strings and having a separate ObservableList for the keys.  I wasn't aware of MapChangeListener and Bindings, either.  Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the Bindings inside the lambda expressions.   Suppose I now want to have the same functionality for an `ObservableMap<String, Shade>` where `Shade` is a custom class with a `StringProperty` member called `Description` (i.e., `getDescription()` returns a `String` and `descriptionProperty()` returns a `StringProperty`) that I would like to display in column2.  How would I change the line `column2.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.valueAt(map, cd.getValue()));`?  Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of 2-level binding is not provided by the bindings API, so you have to programm it on your own by adding a listener to the appropriate property of the map value (and removing it from the property of the old value, when the value is changed to the different one). It's not *that* complicated, but the comments section is not the appropriate place to give a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

This will update your tableView.

```
changeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                map.put("two", "2");
                table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);
                System.out.println(map);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That does work.  However, what if I add something to the table?  For instance, if I change the line `map.put("two","2")` to `map.put("four","Four")`.  In this case the table isn't updated to reflect the change.  Why not?

Comment: Nevermind, I see why now.  So I could change the line `table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2)` to  `table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet()));`  But this seems inelegant because I am recreating an ArrayList and repopulating the table with it.  Furthermore, doing so will "destroy" any sort order the user may have already established by clicking on a column header.  Is there another way?

Comment: For versions >= 8u60 you should probably replace the `getColumns().getColumns().setAll(column1, column2)` with `refresh()`