# JavaFX: Populate TableView with an ObservableMap that has a custom class for its values

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have the following ObservableMap that I would like to display in a `TableView`:

```
private ObservableMap<String, Shape> myShapes = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
```

Where `Shape` is defined as follows:

```
public class Shape {

private StringProperty areaFormula = new SimpleStringProperty();
private IntegerProperty numSides = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public Shape(String areaFormula, int numSides)
{
    this.areaFormula.set(areaFormula);
    this.numSides.set(numSides);
}

public String getAreaFormula() { return areaFormula.get(); }

public void setAreaFormula(String areaFormula) { this.areaFormula.set(areaFormula); }

public StringProperty areaFormulaProperty() { return this.areaFormula; }

public int getNumSides() { return numSides.get(); }

public void setNumSides(int sides) { this.numSides.set(sides); }

public IntegerProperty numSidesProperty() { return this.numSides; }
}
```

I would like the first column of the TableView to be the Map Key (call it `key`), the second column to be `myShapes.get(key).getAreaFormula()`, and the third column to be `myShapes.get(key).getnumSides()`.  And I would like the TableView to automatically update when the Map is changed.

It would also be really nice to make the second and third columns of the `TableView` editable by the user, if possible, with those edits being updated in the Map.

I have already asked stackoverflow about populating a TableView with an ObservableMap such that it will update on changes here:
[Populating a TableView with a HashMap that will update when HashMap changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171820/populating-a-tableview-with-a-hashmap-that-will-update-when-hashmap-changes) .  However as you can see in the discussion there, it does not handle a custom class like I have here.

Here is my solution so far:

```
        ObservableMap<String, Shape> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

        ObservableList<String> keys = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Shape> change) -> {
            boolean removed = change.wasRemoved();
            if (removed != change.wasAdded()) {
                // no put for existing key
                if (removed) {
                    keys.remove(change.getKey());
                } else {
                    keys.add(change.getKey());
                }
            }
        });

        map.put("square", new Shape("L^2", 4));
        map.put("rectangle", new Shape("LW", 4));
        map.put("triangle", new Shape("0.5HB", 3));

        final TableView<String> table = new TableView<>(keys);

        TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Key");

        column1.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> cd.getValue()));

        TableColumn<String, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Value");

        column2.setCellValueFactory( ... );

        table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);
```

The place where I'm stuck is the second-to-last line `column2.setCellValueFactory( ... )`.  I would like `column2` to display the `Shape`'s `getAreaFormula()` `SimpleStringProperty` but I don't know how to set up the `CellValueFactory` to do so.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest, if you create a list of immutable key-value pairs instead of simply a list of keys. This drastically reduces the complexity of the listeners you need to use, since the `MapChangeListener` will always replace an item, if a value is updated and you don't need to add listeners to the `Map` in the `cellValueFactory`s:

#### Key Value pair class

```
public final class MapEntry<K, V> {

    private final K key;
    private final V value;

    public MapEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // check equality only based on keys
        if (obj instanceof MapEntry) {
            MapEntry<?, ?> other = (MapEntry<?, ?>) obj;
            return Objects.equals(key, other.key);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

#### Table creation

```
ObservableMap<String, Shape> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

ObservableList<MapEntry<String, Shape>> entries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Shape> change) -> {
    boolean removed = change.wasRemoved();
    if (removed != change.wasAdded()) {
        if (removed) {
            // no put for existing key
            // remove pair completely
            entries.remove(new MapEntry<>(change.getKey(), (Shape) null));
        } else {
            // add new entry
            entries.add(new MapEntry<>(change.getKey(), change.getValueAdded()));
        }
    } else {
        // replace existing entry
        MapEntry<String, Shape> entry = new MapEntry<>(change.getKey(), change.getValueAdded());

        int index = entries.indexOf(entry);
        entries.set(index, entry);
    }
});

map.put("one", new Shape("a", 1));
map.put("two", new Shape("b", 2));
map.put("three", new Shape("c", 3));

final TableView<MapEntry<String, Shape>> table = new TableView<>(entries);
TableColumn<MapEntry<String, Shape>, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Key");

// display item value (= constant)
column1.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> cd.getValue().getKey()));

TableColumn<MapEntry<String, Shape>, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("formula");
column2.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getValue().areaFormulaProperty());

TableColumn<MapEntry<String, Shape>, Number> column3 = new TableColumn<>("sides");
column3.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getValue().numSidesProperty());

table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2, column3);
```

Comment: entries.indexOf() and index.remove() are O(n) operations.  You want an O(1) solution instead especially if your table is large or frequently updated.

Comment: I have some issue in tableview. Could you please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368501/injavafx-how-to-populate-tableview-with-observablemap